# An event is coming tomorrow

Tags: sentence-construction

> The school sports meet is coming **tomorrow**.

Can "be coming" be followed by "time" here when it means “happening”?

Comment: It should be *meeting*, not *meet* as meet is a verb.

Comment: @Chenmunka "meet" can also serve as a noun.  See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meet  "chiefly US : a large gathering of athletes for a sports competition"; https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/meet "a sports event in which people compete against each other, for example in swimming or running"; See https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/meet " a meeting, gathering, or assembling, as for a sporting event
*a track meet*"; https://www.thefreedictionary.com/meet " the persons or group of men or women who gather for a fox hunt or other sporting event"

Answer (score -1):

### Yes

This is a common construction and often used by fluent speakers.

---

A comment says that "*meey*" is a noun, but "meet" can also serve as a noun.  See:

- [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meet)

> chiefly US : a large gathering of athletes for a sports competition";

- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/meet)

> a sports event in which people compete against each other, for example in swimming or running"

- [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/meet)

> a meeting, gathering, or assembling, as for a sporting event *a track meet*

- [The Free Dictionary](https://www.Thefreedictionary.com/meet)

> The persons or group of men or women who gather for a fox hunt or other sporting event